# About spring mvc configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web

I am trying to build a web app using spring mvc. But so far, when I start server, always get 404.
Could anyone please give me some suggestion about my configuration.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

action-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"><value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value></property>
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

These are under **WEB-INF**.

I have the annotation:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="index.jsp",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

mapping at my controller's only method.
My jsp pages are under **webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/**. My two config files are under **WEB-INF**

Please give me some suggestion!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: A "not found" can have two reasons, the request is not matched to the controller, or the jsp is not found. Have you checked that the controller is invoked? Please add the relevant code part of the controller method to the question, as well as the spring configuration used to enable the controller and controller related annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring MVC, you have to return a ModelAndView in the method with @RequestMapping anotation like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public ModelAndView goHome()
{
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
   return mav;
}
```

The string in modelAndView is depending on your configuration in web.xml. In your situation is home.jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar using Spring with Portlets so please forgive me if this isn't relevant, but does your controller have the following class-level annotations?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
```

For now I'd also lose the parms on your method annotation.

Answer (score 0):

add below segment to your web.xml
It will tell where to fing the dispatcher servlet.

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml,
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```